# Filtering AngularJS Table Based Off Value In Separate Controller

Tags: angularjs, rest, sharepoint, controller, filtering

Ok so I am very new to Angular, only been playing with it for three days now.  I am running into an issue when trying to filter a table I created based on the value of a "select option" in another controller.  Basically I have one controller that performs a REST call to populate a "select" menu dynamically.  Then I have another controller that makes a separate REST call to populate a table.  What I am trying to do is filter the table based off the "value" from the "selected" option.  For example if I choose the "option" with a value of "2", the table would filter to only show results with an "ID" of "2".  I may be going about this in a completely wrong way but from what I am reading I need to create a "service" to store the "value" of the "option" so that I can reference it in the controller that populates the table.  If anyone could provide some incite on how to go about doing this I would greatly appreciate it.  Please see my code bellow...

Angular Code

```
angular.module('restCalls',[])

 // Controller for Project REST Call
.controller('displayProj',function($scope, $http) {

    $http({type: "GET", url:"http://my_api_call/", headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"}})
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.results = data.d.results;
            $scope.projects = [];

            for(i=0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                $scope.projects.push({name: data.d.results[i].Title , id: data.d.results[i].Id});
            };

            $scope.getSelectedOption = function(value) {
                console.log($scope.selectedProject.id); 
            };

        });
})

// Controller for ChargeCode REST Call
.controller('displayCC',function($scope, $http) {

    $http({type: "GET", url:"http://my_api_call/", headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"}})
        .success(function(data) {

            $scope.results = data.d.results;
            $scope.projects = [];

            for(i=0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                $scope.projects.push({id: data.d.results[i].Master_x0020_ID, cc: data.d.results[i].Title, name: data.d.results[i].deltek_x0020_name});
            }

        })
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div data-ng-app="restCalls" class="ng-scope">
   <div id="project_menu_select" data-ng-controller="displayProj" class="ng-scope">
      <p class="ng-binding">ID of selected project is:​​​​ {{selecteProject.id}} </p> 
      <select data-ng-model="selectedProject" data-ng-options="project.name for project in projects" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty form-control ng-touched ng-untouched" data-ng-change="getSelectedOption()">
      </select>​ </div>
   <div id="charge_codes_table" data-ng-controller="displayCC" class="ng-scope"> 
      <table class="table table-striped"> 
         <thead> 
            <tr> 
               <th>Project ID</th> 
               <th>Charge Code</th> 
               <th>Deltek Name</th> 
            </tr> 
         </thead> 
         <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <td data-ng-if="project.id == (option value)">{{project.id}}</td>
        <td data-ng-if="project.id == (option value)">{{project.cc}}</td>
        <td data-ng-if="project.id == (option value)">{{project.name}}</td>
        </tr> 
         </tbody> 
      </table> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you have both table and select option in one page. Better to use single controller for both.

You can also use common parent controller for both of these controllers.

**OR**

You can use $rootScope to share the variables. Set as $rootScope.selectedValue = 2 from one controller and then you can access this as $rootScope.selectedValue from another controller.

**OR**

You can use services to share the functions and variables as follows,

```
app.service("shared", function () {
var selectedOption = {};
return {
    getSelectedOption: function () {
        return selectedOption;
    },
    setSelectedOption: function (value) {
        selectedOption = value;
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the help.  I will look into these methods.